# Entity Objects vs Value Objects - Hibernate and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, model-view-controller, entity

Okay. I am getting a little confused here...

Lets say I have a class called `User`.

```
   class User {
     // all variables
     // all getters and setters
   }
```

Now, I use JSR 303 validation and put `@NotNull`, `@Range`, etc here for the variables.

I use this as Form / Command object. Meaning, when a form a submitted, the values are validated and `BindingResult` gives me errors.

1. Should this be used as in Entity Object for Hibernate as well? (If so, I need to add other Hibernate annotations like `@Entity`, `@Id`, `@Column`, etc on top of Validation annotations)
2. When we load the data from Database, do these validations kick in as well? (If yes, what if the data is already existing, and do not confirm to the validations?)
3. Where do we normally write business validations, like for example, country exists or not in the database, xyz value exists in a different table, etc?

Questions arise here as well:
 - User form may not have all the fields that exist in the User class
 - Database table User may have more fields or less fields than User class
 - Form may have fields from different objects as well, say User and and Order.

How do we handle these?

Trying to wrap my mind around it

Comment: No you shouldn't expose your entity objects to the presentation layer. You can use Spring validation framework for both business and the presentation layer. Do you have validations different from the DB constraints?

Comment: @user2033853  So are you saying I should have two objects one for front end and another one for Domain / Entity? How do we name them? Any references?

Comment: You can take a look at the Domain Driven Design : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

Answer (score 1):

1. No you shouldn't mix entities objects and values objects. Entities objects are for DB mapping and values objects are used in the presentation layer.
2. To validate an object annoted, you need to use a `Validator` (commonly used with a `DataBinder`. [Spring validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html))
3. Is it DB constraints or backend validation?

For your last question, that's one of the reason to have 2 differentes objects for your presentation layer and your persistence layer. This way values objects can match what is displayed or input by the user (Form).

Comment: this is a bogus use of "value objects", you must be thinking of DTOs.

Comment: @NathanHughes Any reference to what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Kevin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object. also you could see Evans' book Domain Driven Design.

Answer (score 1):

**Entity object** is an object of our plain old java class(POJO) Model/Business class, which needs to be persisted in a database using Hibernate, while **Value Type** object is an object of another class but it is stored as a part of Entity object within a database table.

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address{
    private  String country;
    private String city;
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    private postalCode;
}
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private ing age;
    private Address address;
}
}
```

So after running this code in spring and hibernate project you will see Person table in database is created with it's attributes and Address class attributes.
For more information, I suggest reading this:
[https://www.decodejava.com/hibernate-value-type-object.htm][1]